# Fixed Dimension Background Image

Tags: css, background-image

I used a background image with dimension 1120 X 714 pixels. The length and width ratio should be proportional w/ it's dimension so that the image will not look distorted.

The webpage that will use the background-image have a fixed width of 1024px. In my css, I have below:

```
body{
    background: black url("background.jpg") no-repeat fixed center;
    background-size: 1120px 100%;
}
```

The css above will make the length of the background-image 100%. Depending on the resolution or the browser dimension, the background-image will get distorted.

Width is not a problem here.

What are other approach for this having a fixed dimension of background image?

Should I use `background-size: 1120px 714px;`?

Answer (score 0):

When you set the background-size: the first value is the width and the second one is the height.
So if you want to make the length of the image 100% then write:

```
background-size: 100% 714px;
```

I presume 714px is the height of the image...

Answer (score 0):

You need not specify the background size at all. The code below should be enough.

```
body{
    background: black url("background.jpg") no-repeat center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```